# Fold expression: iterate over variadic template type parameter to check compile-time conditions on the comprising types

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

The idea I have in mind is simple: in a variadic class template, I want to check some compile-time condition on the types. In this case, I want to find out if a certain type is in the pack or not. This is what the code might have looked like with C++17's fold expressions, but obviously that's not the valid syntax. How to implement this?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class... Types>
struct TypesPack
{
    template <typename T>
    static constexpr bool hasType() {
        return std::is_same<T, Types>::value || ... || false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Since you're using C++17, you can take advantage of the convenient `_v` additions to traits: `std::is_same_v<T, U>` == `std::is_same<T, U>::value`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
static constexpr bool hasType() {
    return (std::is_same<T, Types>::value || ...);
}
```

A fold-expression must be parenthesized, and you're allowed to omit the `false` when using `||` as the operator.

Comment: Will it also work if there's only one type in the pack?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Yes, it will even work if there are zero.